# iOS Framework as Shared Lib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

### Environment

- Xcode 8
- Objective C
- iOS

### Introduction

- Dynamic/Shared Libraries are supported on xcode for iOS8 and above
- Before iOS8 all Frameworks were compiled by xcode as Static libraries bundled w/ the associated resources
- Since iOS8, all Frameworks are compiled as Dynamic/Shared Libraries.

### Given the above

**Having a pre iOS8 ( static lib ) framework, what would it take to make it compile as a Dynamic/Shared library ?**

Answer (score 0):

### The type of the framework executable can be determined as presented in the following image

[image]